# Bumblebee X Server Not Avaliable

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee

I've installed bumblebee for better battery life, and after installing bumblebee, i've seen some advance in battery performance.

However, I can't use optirun command, since running it gives me that the bumblebee X server is not available.

The logs are here: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/760115/ .

UBUNTU ONEIRIC OCELOT, I5-460M, GT310M, noveau driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general setup for Bumblebee is not that simple, be sure you have accomplished all the steps as described here http://www.ivegotavirus.com/blog/2011/11/06/how-to-get-optimus-working-on-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric/

Comment: thnx.. 'll try that!

Comment: urrr.. Could you tell me how do I find out my acpi_call code? It is not listed in the provided site......

Comment: @MinSikCHO The new Bumblebee version can autodetect PM features, see http://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969